# Deleting a stored procedure belonging to sys schema

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, permissions, database-schema

I have created to stored procedure:

```
dbo.stp_getDubletss
```

somehow there has also been created a procedure named

```
sys.stp_getDubletss
```

when I try and drop procedure

```
sys.stp_getDubletss
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot drop the procedure 'sys.stp_getDobbeltmaerker', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

I don't seem to be able to give my user permission to delete that procedure.
I'm stumped.

Comment: What is the statement you are using to drop the `sys.stp_getDubletss` SP?

Comment: You've mentioned two different procedure names: `stp_getDubletss` or `stp_getDobbeltmaerker`. Which is correct? Or does trying to drop one really give an error with the name of the other one? Can you show the SQL `DROP` command you're using? Are you logged in with a `sysadmin` account?

Comment: My bad. I was translating from my own language into english and forgot to translate that one.

Comment: The only way around the problem I found was to backup the data from the DB. Nuke it from orbit (the only way to be sure) and then make a new DB without the offending object. Then import the data again.

Answer (score 0):

[Create a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345415.aspx)

> Requires CREATE PROCEDURE permission in the database and ALTER
>   permission on the schema in which the procedure is being created.

[Delete a Stored Procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345358.aspx)

> Requires ALTER permission on the schema to which the procedure
>   belongs, or CONTROL permission on the procedure.

Have you used the same account for creation and deletion?

Comment: you see. I haven't created the objects. One day the clients began reporting odd behaviour from the DB. I logged on to find it like that. The only login that is supposed to have anything to do with the DB is one controlled by me. But that does not guarantee others can't log in and change it. But that just seems ludicris.